# PHP $_post method to be used in multiple pages

Tags: php

Good day all i am busy building a dashboard im using PHP i have a log in system where by i use $_post how to my main page now i want to get that data in the next page but i am getting stuck

```
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-comments fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <div class="huge">26</div><!-------- need to crate a php code to calculate this -->
                                    <div>Actions Results!</div><!-------- this is for actions taken by agents  -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="Actions.php"  method="post" name="sessionform">
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="sessionid" value="<?php echo $sessionid?>" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

//sessionid is my $_post data

Comment: its `$_POST` not `$_post`

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you echo $sessionid, but not $_POST['sessionid'].

**Edit:** Change this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sessionid" value="<?php echo $sessionid?>" />
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="sessionid" value="<?php echo $_POST['sessionid']; ?>" />
```

Comment: i seem to still get the error on the page im posting to my new page
$user = $_POST['sessionid'];

Comment: I just looked at the code. There was a semicolon missing. Check my answer now, I edited it. You have to add an ';'

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code too...

```
<input type="hidden" name="sessionid" value=<?php echo '"'.$_POST['sessionid'].'"'; ?>
```

Comment: i am still getting this error on my new page Undefined index 
i use it as follows $ad = $_POST['sessionid'];

Comment: ok brother replace with it then :  <input type="hidden" name="sessionid" value=<?php if(isset($_POST['sessionid'])) echo '"'.$_POST['sessionid'].'"'; ?>